# Insufficient lamports but my balance already is 7 SOL

Tags: solana-program, anchor-test

I'm trying to transfer sol via smart contract but when I make a transfer tx, it return insufficent lamports, and it says I have 0 lamports.

```
pub fn buy_nft(
        ctx: Context<BuyNft>,
        lamports: Option<u64>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
            system_program::transfer(
                CpiContext::new(
                    ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                    system_program::Transfer {
                        from: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                        to: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                    },
                ),
                lamports.unwrap(),
            )?;
        Ok(())
    }
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyNft<'info> {
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

And this is my unittest

```
            await program.methods.buyNft(
                new anchor.BN(saleAmount)
            )
                .accounts({
                    ownerAuthority: owner.publicKey,
                    buyerAuthority: buyer.publicKey,
                })
                .signers([buyer])
                .rpc();
```

I'm using connection.getBalance and the result is 7 SOL
But somehow the error return "'Transfer: insufficient lamports 0, need 1',"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing using `anchor test`, try checking the `Anchor.toml` file and replace `localnet` to the cluster you're trying to test on

```
[programs.localnet]
my_program = "Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS"

[provider]
cluster = "localnet"
```

If you're manually creating the connection using `@solana/web3.js`, it should looks something like this:

```
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection } from "@solana/web3.js"

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"))
```

If you're testing another way. Run `solana config get` to double check the `RPC URL` is for the cluster you're trying to test on.

You can update the `RPC URL` by running:

`solana config set -u m` (mainnet)

`solana config set -u d` (devnet)

`solana config set -u l` (localhost)